# soundmanager2 pageplayer hide mp3 link

Tags: jquery, mp3, soundcloud, soundmanager2

**Hide music files liks from player**
I am creating customize music player using soundmanager2 pageplayer like this

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/

I want to hide music files links to make my music files secure and undownloaded

currently i am using something like this

```
<ul class="playlist">
  <li><a href="./mpc/audio/CRASH_1.mp3">Song 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="./_mp3/bass.mp3">Song 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="./_mp3/sine,%20square,%20sawtooth,%20rando.mp3">Song 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="./_mp3/1hz-10khz-sweep.mp3">Song 4</a></li>
<ul>
```

### Short Version

Any suggestions to prevent users from stealing mp3 files while using html5 audio tag.

Comment: Sorry but in short, "If you can see or hear it, you can steal it. If you want to protect them then do not post.

Comment: @OzgurEffe dear friend i just want to make it like soundcloud.com in that you cant download link from pagesource

Comment: I dont think SM2 has any feature like hiding this audio links. Why dont you try [jPlayer - The jQuery HTML5 Audio / Video Library](http://jplayer.org/latest/demos/).It is free and open source. Not only will help you with hiding links but also it has many extras.

Comment: @effe hello there. I found this player recently and really like it so far. I am talking about soundmanager, though. There is many features and functionality but one problem. Not like security issues, but links. There is much trouble with those links showing up their urls over the player in Chrome. I tried to make there another attribute and adding into bar-ui this: `link.getAttribute('attr name')`, but nothing happens after I do that. It says there is no url and does nothing. Is there actually any way to make it work without attribute `href`? Thx for attention anyways!

Comment: @effe and talking about jPlayer.. I don't like that player. Is there enough flexibility to make it fully responsive with fixed attachment to the bottom of the page and moving its playlist to the top of the player? It looks like that player actually very ugly and doesn't have even close functionality that soundmanager2 has and is not that changeable as SM2. Anyway, I am looking for very flexible to editing player to use for my project and couldn't find any except this two. Could you recommend some better choises if there is no easy way to fix that href shit with SM2?